# What's the Best Volume Ratio for a 6-month Timeframe?

Tags: volume

Suppose I want to compare a few traded equities to see which has the largest increase in *recent* volume compared to what it has been getting over the past 6 months.

I want to create a ratio based on the two time intervals, but I am unsure what to use and how to decide.

Here are some options:

1. ```
    (previous trading day volume) / 10 day average volume
   ```
2. ```
    (previous trading day volume) / 30 day average volume
   ```
3. ```
    (previous trading day volume) / 1 month average volume
   ```
4. ```
    (3 day average volume) / 10 day average volume
   ```
5. ```
    (3 day average volume) / 30 day average volume
   ```
6. ```
    (3 day average volume) / 1 month average volume
   ```
7. ```
    (5 day average volume) / 10 day average volume
   ```
8. ```
    (5 day average volume) / 30 day average volume
   ```
9. ```
    (5 day average volume) / 1 month average volume
   ```
10. ```
     (10 day average volume) / 1 month average volume
    ```
11. ```
     (3 day average volume) / 3 month average volume
    ```
12. ```
     (5 day average volume) / 3 month average volume
    ```
13. ```
     (10 day average volume) / 3 month average volume
    ```
14. ```
     (3 day average volume) / 6 month average volume
    ```
15. ```
     (5 day average volume) / 6 month average volume
    ```
16. ```
     (10 day average volume) / 6 month average volume
    ```
17. ```
     (1 month average volume) / 6 month average volume
    ```
18. ```
     (3 month average volume) / 6 month average volume
    ```

Comment: How about a more symmetric alternative like: `(5 day average volume)/(5 day average volume 6 months ago)`.

Comment: (the purpose of the moving average being to avoid the impact of a single unusually high volume today or a single unusually low volume 6 months ago, at the cost of a delay in detetcting a true change).